# Unable to connect to MySQL database by hibernate due to MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'dbname' error

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I am facing a strange problem. I am using hibernate and trying to run a sample DB updation code using Hibernate framework. I am using MySQL database @localhost:3306. The name of the schema is "hibernate_test".

I have created a table named as "employee_details" with the below columns:

> EmployeeID, FirstName, SecondName.

Below is the configuration @hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <hibernate-configuration>

        <session-factory>

            <!-- Database connection settings -->
            <property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
            <property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name = "connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test"</property>
            <property name = "connection.username">root</property>
            <property name = "connection.password">mysql123</property>
            <property name = "connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

            <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
        </session-factory>

    </hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my hibernate-mapping code :

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name = "com.somnath.test.Employee" table = "employee_details">
            <id name = "employeeID">
                <generator class ="assigned"></generator>
            </id>
            <property name="firstName"></property>
            <property name="lastName"></property>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

I am getting the below error while running the application:

```
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'hibernate_test"'
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. As I have searched many similar problems regarding the issue, but yet to get any valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `"` in your database name; at the end of your database name. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Man.. a very very silly mistake from me .. Thanks a Lot. :)